# How to use Event keycode in PDF Form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

I am trying not to use backspace and delete button in a text box in PDF form by using JavaScript. But the following code is not working.

```
 if(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46){
         app.alert("alert box");
 }
 event.rc = false;
```

Any solutions for this